# Is there a Unicode-aware LC_COLLATE sort order which respects punctuation?

Tags: linux, shell, unicode, sorting, locale

As far as I can tell, setting the environment variable `LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8` changes four things compared to `LC_COLLATE=c`, regarding how programs like `ls` will sort files:

1. Unicode characters are preserved (rather than being replaced with `??` garbage)
2. **Accents and diacritical marks** don't affect sort order
3. **Case differences** don't affect sort order
4. **Punctuation characters** (such as dots) don't affect sort order

Feature 1 is must-have in this day and age.
Features 2 and 3 are great too, since they make it more convenient to deal with real-life Unicode filenames.
Feature 4, on the other hand, is something that I find really anti-productive in my day-to-day work, since it often produces counter-intuitive sort orders for Linux filenames - where dots tend to be used to separate suffixes or to indicate dotfiles. I really can't imagine why anyone thought it would be a good idea to ignore dots when sorting filenames.

For example:

```
$ touch foo.txt foo2.txt foó3.txt foo4.txt

$ LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8 ls
foo2.txt  foó3.txt  foo4.txt  foo.txt

$ LC_COLLATE=c ls
foo.txt  foo2.txt  foo4.txt  fo??3.txt
```

Neither is satisfactory. This is how I'd want those files to be sorted:

```
foo.txt  foo2.txt  foó3.txt  foo4.txt
```

In other words, just like with `LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8`, except that punctuations are treated as significant characters (which are sorted before letters).

**Does any LC_COLLATE setting exist which does this?**

If there is no punctuation-respecting one that supports all features 1-3, is there at least one that supports feature 1 (i.e. sort like `LC_COLLATE=c` but don't garble Unicode chars)?

Answer (score 2):

Problem number 1 is that `LC_COLLATE=c` is an invalid locale. You need a capital `C` (`LC_COLLATE=C`):

```
$ LC_COLLATE=c ls -1a
./
../
.sharp
.zharp
Sharp
sharp
szharp
zharp
??harp

$ LC_COLLATE=C ls -1a
./
../
.sharp
.zharp
Sharp
sharp
szharp
zharp
ßharp
```

I don't know how to do unicode-aware sorting *without* sorting filenames starting with a dot on top though (searching for an answer to this is how I ended up here) :-/